# MySql Trigger: can't retrieve one specific column from NEW in after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 3 tables:

**pp088_project_tasks**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pp088_project_tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_list_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `due_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `assigned_to_company_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_to_user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `completed_by_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_by_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `task_list_id` (`task_list_id`),
  KEY `completed_on` (`completed_on`),
  KEY `created_on` (`created_on`),
  KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=76 ;
```

**pp088_project_task_lists**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pp088_project_task_lists` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `milestone_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `project_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `due_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `score` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_private` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completed_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `completed_by_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `milestone_id` (`milestone_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `completed_on` (`completed_on`),
  KEY `created_on` (`created_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

**gantt_tasks**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gantt_tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `progress` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sortorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `projectID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_evento` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `idPier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=48 ;
```

I created an AFTER INSERT trigger on the 'pp088_project_tasks' table to insert into 'gantt_tasks'

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_gantt_task` AFTER INSERT ON `pp088_project_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

declare project_id int;
declare duracion int;

set project_id=(select project_id from pp088_project_task_lists where id=NEW.task_list_id);
set duracion=(select DATEDIFF(NEW.due_date,NEW.start_date));

insert into gantt_tasks (text,start_date,duration,projectID,idPier) values (NEW.text,NEW.start_date,duracion,project_id,NEW.id); 

END
```

but the problem is with the setting of the project_id variable which sets the gantt_tasks field projectID to NULL because that query cannot retrieve the value using NEW.task_list_id, even if I use that value directly on the insert just to check the value it sets the gantt_tasks field projectID to 0......The strange thing is that if I use other values of the NEW they all work, it's just that field, the insert is successful for all of the other fields on gantt_tasks. I checked and the types are the same, and so the collation as well.
The first two tables are from a project manager called projectPier and the gantt_tasks table is one I created for a gantt chart(DHTMLX gantt chart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... but the problem is with the setting of the `project_id` variable which sets the `gantt_tasks` field `projectID` to `NULL` because that query cannot retrieve the value using `NEW.task_list_id`, even if I use that value directly on the insert just to check the value it sets the `gantt_tasks` field `projectID` to `0`*

**Reason** is very much *visible*.

You have a variable `project_id` whose name matches that of a column in the table.
And when you use column name without a table qualifier, there arises a conflict on the names. And priority will be given to the local variable over column.

In your case, due to the statement

```
declare project_id int;
```

the default value of `project_id` would be `zero`. And hence, the output of the statement

```
set project_id=(select project_id from pp088_project_task_lists 
                 where id=NEW.task_list_id);
```

would be a `zero`. And hence the same is used in the `insert` statement.

**Options**:

1. Change local variable name to something relevant.
2. Use table name to qualify the column name.

**Sample Example**: (using option 1)

Make following changes to your code and it should be working.

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_gantt_task` AFTER INSERT ON `pp088_project_tasks`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  declare _project_id int default 0;
  declare _duracion int default 0;

  select project_id into _project_id 
    from pp088_project_task_lists 
   where id = NEW.task_list_id;

  select DATEDIFF( NEW.due_date, NEW.start_date ) into _duracion;

  insert into gantt_tasks ( text, start_date, duration, projectID, idPier ) 
         values( NEW.text, NEW.start_date, _duracion, _project_id, NEW.id ); 
END;

//

delimiter ;
```

**Sample Example**: (using option 2)

Make following changes to your code and it should be working.

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_gantt_task` AFTER INSERT ON `pp088_project_tasks`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  declare project_id int default 0;
  declare duracion int default 0;

  set project_id := ( select tl.project_id 
                        from pp088_project_task_lists tl
                       where tl.id = NEW.task_list_id );

  set duracion := select DATEDIFF( NEW.due_date, NEW.start_date );

  insert into gantt_tasks ( text, start_date, duration, projectID, idPier ) 
         values( NEW.text, NEW.start_date, duracion, project_id, NEW.id ); 
END;

//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: It's not working, I tried the option 1, and the field projectID in gantt_tasks is still set to 0.

In **pp088_project_task_lists**  table I have the following data on the fields that matter here

    id=2 and project_id=4 


The task created on **pp088_project_tasks** should have task_id_list set to 2, and the projectID inserted on **gantt_tasks** should be 4, but it's still inserting 0   :S

Comment: Execute the `select project_id ...` statement separately with `NEW task_list_id` inserted and check if `project_id` fetched is a `zero` or something else.

Comment: I just execute on phpmyadmin separately

SELECT project_id
FROM pp088_project_task_lists
WHERE id =2

and it returns 1 row, which is project_id 4, the correct result, so, I don't know which is the problem

Comment: I have also tried the option B you gave me, I get NULL inserted in the field projectID in gantt_tasks, all the other fields are inserted ok.....

Comment: `WHERE id = 2`. Is the `id` value same as `NEW.task_list_id` ? If yes, it should not return `NULL` on using option 2 solution.

Comment: I have used the option B again exactly as you put in there, I copy and pasted. Both of the id's are 2. In the definition of the column projectID in the gantt task I put int(10), unsigned , cannot be null
but still not working(before it was set to allow NULL in thi field, but it just inserted NULL). Now when I try to create the task it says an sql message "projectID cannot be null".......I atonished, I can't understand what's happening

Comment: Not able to think or assume on what is going on behind. The code suggested should work on ideal conditions.

Comment: May be some sequence of steps would help to debug. Like: 1. your `insert into pp088_project_tasks` statement with input parameters. 2. `select from pp088_project_task_lists` statement output for the given task id.